# Count number of values in python

Tags: python, list, count

I have a list look like this:

```
Lux = ([ 0 0 0 0 0 120 120 120 120 120 240 240 240 240 240 0 0 0 0 0 120 120 120 120 120])
```

I want to count how many zeros I have, but only from the 14 place, and let say until 16 place
The answer will be in this case 2.
I know that count function count all the appearance.
How can I do it, but with out loop? I want this when I'm already in two loops, and don't want to add another one.

Thank you.

Comment: That's not a python list, FYI.

Comment: Why don't you slice the list before you count? Something like `count(Lux[14:16])`.

Comment: Evert,
I want somthing like this:
  valueInLux = Lux[i] #Lux[i] = 0
  LuxNumberOfRows = Lux.count(valueInLux)

Where Lux is the list, but for this I want only to run from 14 to 16.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `list.count` and `slicing`:

```
>>> lis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 240, 240, 240, 240, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120]
>>> lis[14:].count(0)
5
>>> lis[14:17].count(0)
2
```

Another option is to use `sum` and a generator expression, but this is going to be very slow compared to `list.count`:

```
>>> sum(1 for i in xrange(14, len(lis)) if lis[i]==0)
5
>>> sum(1 for i in xrange(14, 17) if lis[i]==0)
2
```

**Timing comparisons:**

```
In [4]: lis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 240, 240, 240, 240, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12
0, 120, 120, 120, 120]*10**5                                                                     

In [5]: %timeit lis[14:].count(0)                                                                
10 loops, best of 3: 64.7 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit sum(1 for i in xrange(14, len(lis)) if lis[i]==0)                                
1 loops, best of 3: 307 ms per loop
```

Comment: list.count and slicing was exactly what I need! Thank you!